# Coloring textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am trying to highlight specific color of the Textview from a certain position of textview.For e.g in the textview string I want to highlight white color from 0 to 15 position and red color from 16th to end of String.Is it possible? can anyone give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `Spannable Text` you can do it

```
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString("I know just how to whisper");        
WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 15, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

Comment: I am able to change the color with your code , but when i use this in getview() method of listview the next list item refreshes the original color.how to get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

`TextView` has an attribute `textColor`. Once set it will color the entire `TextView.` 
I don't think there's something built in Android to achieve what you need, but an idea is to truncate your long `TextView` from the positions you need, into several small `TextViews`, and draw each with its own color.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Get count of your string 

  int length = YourString.length();
then check with if condtion and set like this.

  TextView tt;
  int color = Integer.parseInt("bdbdbd", 16)+0xFF000000);
  tt.setTextColor(color);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use WebView and put HTML code inside...

```
String html = "<div><span style="background-color:red">SOME TEXT</span><span style="background-color:blue">SOME TEXT</span></div>"
wv.loadData(html, "text/html", Encoding.UTF_8.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a direct method to set different colors in a text view.

You can try setting html formatted text to your text view to achieve your goal.
For example;

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourText));
```

in the above code, *yourText* is html formatted string and you can create the html text as per you application logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with [ForegroundColorSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html) to the `TextView` For example -

```
TextView tView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
tView.setText("Italic, highlighted, bold.", TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
Spannable WordtoSpan = (Spannable) tView.getText();
WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), 0, 15, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tView.setText(WordtoSpan);
```